# Как отсортировать json, помогите найти ошибку

Tags: jquery, json

Есть подобный код:

```
$.getJSON('http://shop-42251-50.myinsales.ru/collection/tehnika.json', function(data) {
 data.sort(function(a,b){
 return a.data.products.id-b.data.products.id
   });
 });
```

Пишет data.sort не есть функцией, помогите найти ошибку или статью как делается сортировка json, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый день. Я полагаю в вашем случае это будет выглядеть примерно вот так.

```
$.getJSON('http://shop-42251-50.myinsales.ru/collection/tehnika.json', function(data) {
    data['products'].sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.id - b.id;
    });
});
```